# msbuild -p:outputdir=c:\mydir being ignored

Tags: msbuild

I'm running msbuild from the command line with the following:

```
msbuild mysolution.sln -p:outputdir=c:\mydir
```

When I run this, the outputdir is being ignored and the default specified in the csproj file is being used.

The MSDN doc for this tool says that I should be able to override the build directory using this parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I made an error here with using -p rather than /p. The MSDN doco for the MSBuild Command Line Reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) incorrectly refers to outputdir.

Comment: You should make your comment and answer instead.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You should use `OutputPath` and more important you should use the right syntax :

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /p:OutputPath=c:\mydir
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this one. I think you mean the /p rather than -p when you referred to the syntax problem. I was actually using the /p in cmd.exe but got it wrong here - too much PowerShell. As for the Outputpath, dead on. Thanks.

Comment: It also worked for me.. I was usint /P:outputdir instead of /p:outputpath

Comment: Ensure to leave off the ending `\ `.  `/p:OutputPath=c:\mydir` and NOT `/p:OutputPath=c:\mydir\ `

Comment: I tried this, but MSBuild seems to ignore `OutputPath` when the linker output directory is specified in the project options.

Comment: If this didn't work, 1: Consider using `OutDir` instead of `OutputPath`. 2: Make sure the `OutDir` is the first thing listed for your `/p:` args.

Comment: `OutputPath` had no effect in my case but `OutDir` did it

Answer (score 9):

Note that `OutputPath` is preferred over `OutDir`. The documentation used to be wrong about this, but I see that they've finally fixed it.

Beyond that, it's difficult to say exactly what the problem is, since you didn't show the exact path that you're passing as a parameter. There are two possible problems that I can imagine:

1. The `OutputPath` option specifies the path to the output directory *relative to the project directory*. That means you can't set it to a global path like `C:\mydir`. I assume it is unable to find the path you specified, and so it defaults to the one specified in your project file.
2. If the path that you're actually specifying as a parameter contains *spaces*, the command is likely to fail. I believe you need to wrap the path in quotes and append an extra backslash to the end of the path string.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Cody. The doco I've been reading (The MSBuild Command Line Reference for VS 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) uses OutputDir. I'd say we're reading different pages. I've now also built successfully, using an absolute directory reference like c:\mydir.

Comment: @Mike: These things happen when you document the exact same features in so many different places. I'm not really sure if you're saying that `OutputPath` didn't work for you? `OutDir` *will* still work.

Comment: GUYS. There is no `OutputDir` parameter. There is only `OutputPath` and `OutDir`. Stop adding to the confusion.

Comment: FYI - It does appear that OutputPath can be an absolute path.

Comment: @StevenLiekens I think `OutputDir` is from older versions of MSBuild. I could see that used in my csproj files. They compile just fine with modern VS.

Comment: Have you got a reference for "`OutputPath` is preferred over `OutDir`"? According to https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/87#issuecomment-101467157 it's the other way around. And https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170 doesn't even include `OutputPath` in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be using **OutputPath**.