# How to prevent msbuild from adding "Release" to Output Path?

Tags: c#, msbuild

msbuild outputs compiled artifacts to `bin/Release/` and `obj/Release` when I've specified the output path as `bin/`. I'm trying to perform this build in CI so I'm using this command `

```
msbuild.exe /nologo /p:Configuration=Release
```

`

The .csproj file for this project contains this entry

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I manually added the `OutputPath`.

After looking around SO, I tried adding the `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` and `AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath` keys but didn't seem to help. What option do I need to stop the "Release" directory from being appended to output path?

Comment: Is `x64` your default Platform? What happens if you specify `/p:Platform=x64` explicitly?

Comment: It should work, but I've always done it via the project's **Property** page inside Visual Studio and could enter values like **U:\Foo\out** so I don't see why yours wouldn't work.  Try the editor.

Comment: Try specifying the OutputPath - msbuild mysolution.sln /p:OutputPath=c:\mydir - Previously answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965507/msbuild-poutputdir-c-mydir-being-ignored

Comment: @AnthonyG. Why isn't the OutputPath in the .csproj respected? Also, I don't want to build the entire solution since it contains multiple projects, I just want to build the one project.

Comment: @AnthonyG. I've tried `msbuild.exe /nologo /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputDir=bin\` to no avail. Also, I need to use a relative path as this is for a CI/CD setup.

Comment: @JoeSewell That's not an option, this needs to build projects that may or may not be x64.

Comment: @user20660706 The reason that Joe is asking if you tested with `/p:Platform=x64` is because the part of the project file that you shared is only used when the value of `Platform` is x64 and the value of `Configuration` is release.

Answer (score 1):

In the project snippet provided, the `PropertyGroup` is conditional on the Configuration being Release and the Platform being x64. Out of the box, the default value of Platform in a C# project is 'AnyCPU'.

The following command line will set the Configuration and Platform appropriately for the `PropertyGroup` to be evaluated:

```
msbuild /nologo /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64
```

If you want to set the `OutputPath` regardless of the value of Platform but only when Configuration is Release, remove `OutputPath` from the existing `PropertyGroup` and create a new `PropertyGroup` as follows:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

To always change the `OutputPath`, regardless of Configuration and Platform, remove the `Condition`:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: It should also be noted, that order is important. If the "unconditional" property group is followed by a conditional one (that matches the current settings) and that redefines the OutputPath to something else, that value will be taken. IOW, if you use the unconditional approach, make sure you don't set OutputPath again anywhere later.

Comment: I ended up doing something somewhat like this. I changed a PropertyGroup which contained conditionals that set the Platform to 'AnyCPU' if it was empty. I changed that to set it to 'x64' if empty.